# Navigation width for iPad

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, web

I am looking to fix how my Navigation looks while viewing the website vertically using an iPad. I would like the JobSpark logo to remain on the left hand side, with the page links running horizontally beside it. As you can see in the image below, things do not line up very well. Any help on this would be great.

Below is a link to my site

http://jobspark.ca/

[image]

Comment: Please include code. It would be much easier than us having to debug your entire website.

Comment: The problem is, if they don't fit, they don't fit, so what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: I am using Squarespace so dont have much for html. Is there a way to shrink the logo size so allow the page links to all fit horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

- You could reduce the padding between your logo and the nav links and between the nav links in general.
- Are you testing on an ipad? I thought the ipad res is 2048-by-1536? I don't see the nav wrap as you show until I get to 753.
- What are you using to determine when to snap to the mobile menu? You could set up **@media only screen and (min-device-width: XXXpx) and (max-device-width: XXXpx)**.

Best, R